# Bootstrap - Input (number) with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, input, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I have some problem with Chrome.

[image]

For example :

```
<input type="number" size="25" name="whatever" id="whatever" required />
```

When there is a number input as you can see the number is cut.

And also an another problem, at the left you can see the input using Firefox/IE, at the right the input using Chrome.

[image]

```
<form class="form-search pull-right">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" class="span2 search-query">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Rechercher</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My second problem was solved by addind arround the input :

```
<div class="row">
```

My first problem was solved by adding :

```
form input[type='number']{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```